# How to make the result of callgrind human readable

Tags: c++, profiling, valgrind, profiler, callgrind

I'm trying to use `valgrind --tool=callgrind` to profile my C++ program on Ubuntu. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout<<"hello world"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it: `g++ main.cpp -g`

valgrind: `valgrind --tool=callgrind ./a.out`

Then I get a file named `callgrind.out.1153`.

Then I use the tool [gprof2dot](https://github.com/jrfonseca/gprof2dot) and the command `dot`:

```
python gprof2dot.py -f callgrind -n10 -s callgrind.out.1153 > valgrind.dot
dot -Tpng valgrind.dot -o valgrind.png
```

However, this `png` is like this:

[image]

For me this is really hard to read.

So is it possible to make `callgrind` more human readable? For example, can it show me only the execution time of each function of my code or the execution time of my code line by line?

Comment: Have you tried KCachegrind?

Comment: @user6556709   I can't because my working PC is not allowed to install KCachegrind.

Comment: Valgrind comes with command line tool [cg_annotate](http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/cg-manual.html#cg-manual.profile) . It is able to output execution time per line.

Comment: First of all, the ___grind profilers only do CPU time, not I/O time. Second, a "hello world" program is almost totally I/O. The smaller-than-miniscule time it spends in CPU is almost totally spent in the I/O library functions, as you can see, and, even if you understood them, you can't change them, so how can this help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not super user-friendly, but I think this does what the OP wants:

```
callgrind_annotate --tree=both --inclusive=yes --auto=yes --show-percs=yes callgrind.out.${pid} > tree.${pid}
```

This creates a text file with two sections.  The first section is a summary of profiled functions, sorted by the time spent in each.  Example of one function:

```
 3,090,761,742,907 (22.39%)  < /home/me/proj/src/dir0/file0.cpp:caller0() (79,173,695x) [/home/me/proj/build/reldbg/lib/libzero.so]
   768,380,030,255 ( 5.57%)  < /home/me/proj/src/dir0/file1.cpp:caller1(unsigned int) (19,814,000x) [/home/me/proj/build/reldbg/lib/libzero.so]
 3,861,537,817,283 (27.97%)  *  /home/me/proj/src/dir0/Abc.cpp:Abc::Abc() [/home/me/proj/build/reldbg/lib/libzero.so]
 2,458,035,862,297 (17.80%)  >   /home/me/proj/src/dir1/file2.h:callee0() (99,049,427x) [/home/me/proj/build/reldbg/lib/libone.so]
 1,378,046,252,252 ( 9.98%)  >   /home/me/proj/src/dir0/file3.cpp:callee1() (99,049,427x) [/home/me/proj/build/reldbg/lib/libzero.so]
```

The profiled function has the asterisk, its callers have less-than, the functions it calls have greater-than.

The second section is annotated source code, with the amount of time allocated on each line.  For example:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Auto-annotated source: /home/me/proj/src/dir0/file1.cpp
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ir                      

-- line 37 ----------------------------------------
 7,822,093,316 ( 0.06%)          for (uint32 i = 0; i < VEC_SIZE; i++)
             .                   {
21,018,143,872 ( 0.15%)              data[i].reset();
110,822,940,416 ( 0.80%)  => /home/me/proj/src/dir0/abc.cpp:Abc::reset() (1,910,740,352x)
             .                   }
```